# jcrop loads old image

Tags: jquery, jcrop

I am using jcrop for crop functionality.when i select image and close popup without cropping image and choose other image it shows me old image which i selected previously and show image which i have recently selected.And come time it doesn't load image in crop area. I have written following code

```
if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
            jQuery('#target').attr('src', e.target.result);
            image.src = e.target.result;
           };
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
```

}

Comment: Hi there, please help me as well with this if you get rid.